# Refining morphisms of spaces to morphisms of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given two schemes $X$ and $Y$, and a continuous map $f$ between the underlying spaces, what conditions are necessary for the existence of a map of sheaves $g:\mathcal{O}_Y\rightarrow f_*\mathcal{O}_X$ such that $(f, g)$ defines a morphism of schemes?

Assume $X$ and $Y$ are locally of finite type over $\mathrm{Spec}\:k$ for $k$ an algebraically closed field, if that makes life any easier.

Some conditions are necessary because there is no morphism of schemes $\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{R}$ (cardinality). Alternatively, there is [no](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04DE) morphism of schemes from the $k$-affine line with double origin to the $k$-affine line that restricts to a homeomorphism on the underlying spaces (albeit there is a homeomorphism).

Comment: According to wikipedia, a morphism of schemes is just a morphism of the underlying locally ringed spaces. So I guess you just want your map g of sheaves to induce a map of local rings (i.e. preserving the maximal ideal) on each stalk. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphism_of_schemes

Comment: @SamGunningham note that OP does not have "your map g of sheaves". So I am not sure how your comment addresses the question.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question...